# Angular2 CLI "ng serve" not working on windows

Tags: angular, npm, angularfire2

When trying to run **"ng serve"** on my windows cmd I am getting the following Error:

WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been in
itialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'tslint'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?,
entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, plugins?, profile?,
recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, s
tats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configura
tion.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in mo
dule.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these
 options to the loader:

PS: I am following https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md to install & setup AngularFire2.

Before getting this error I did:

1. npm install -g angular-cli
2. npm install -g typings
3. npm install -g typescript
4. ng new oct25
5. cd oct25
6. ng serve   //This is where I am getting Error

[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem related to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2234). Switching to beta.22 fixed the problem. Not sure if it's something that's been resolved or not

Comment: @peeskillet  I have used the latest built as of today

Comment: Try changing the global webpack to beta.22, as mentioned in the link. Like I said I am not sure if this is something that has already been resolved, but you can try to use the work-around, see if it works for you

Comment: @peeskillet How to change the global webpack to beta.22?

Comment: Actually, I don't know. After reading, it seems this issue was fixed in the cli beta.15. I think latest is 18. So it shouldn't be a problem. And with the webpack version fix, it seems that cli should not be dependent on the global webpack, but an internal one. So I don't know if fixing the global one will do anything. But you can try. `npm uninstall -g webpack`, then install it again `npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 -g`

Comment: @peeskillet Didn't work.. same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try deleting node_ modules folder and npm install again. It worked..!!